# GNOME maximize window hidden shortcut

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, shortcuts

Upon configuring my keyboard shortcuts for my gnome desktop, I discovered, that I cannot get rid of a hidden shortcut for maximizing the focused window with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>. I am using on GNOME Shell 3.24.2 on Ubuntu 17.04.

If I open the keyboard shortcuts in the settings it shows that the shortcut is set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>, and this shortcut is active too.

I have similar issues with all the other `resize-window` key-bindings. Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Same for me. I don't get where this ```Super+up``` shortcut is defined and how to get rid of it. I'd like to associate it with "Volume up"...

Comment: @JulienV Since then I have received an answer for this question here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/952899/how-to-find-hidden-keybinding-to-maximize-windows-in-ubuntu-gnome?answertab=votes#tab-top